# How to change width of UITableViewRowAction?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I have a `UITableViewRowAction` with two features - "Favourite" and "Share". Due to the fact that they are two different sized words, the features have different widths.

How do I change the width of the two features?

Here is an image to show the features:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add blanks in your title: "  text  "